# NET USE - How to get list of all shares (elevated, non-elevated)

Tags: windows, network-share, windows-command-prompt, net-use, user-permissions

The command:

> NET USE

Will display open connections by any process of current user. But, if command prompt (cmd.exe, or any shell) is non-elevated, it would display only connections opened by non-elevated processes. To see shares open by elevated processes, we need to use Command Prompt elevated.

How to view all shares/connections opened by same user (i.e. current user) - irrespective of elevation of processes which opened the remote share (for example, from (non-elevated) Windows Explorer) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't built-in functionality to do what you're looking for. The elevated context's "mappings" are separate from the limited-user context, as you're seeing. You could write a script to perform the `NET USE` as both the limited and elevated contexts and concatenate the results, but there's no single API or command-line tool that I'm aware of that does what you're looking for.

Comment: How to write such script, that runs elevated as well as non elevated? A Batch file, A PowerShell script?

Comment: Whatever you're comfortable with. I'd use a batch script (because I'm lazy). I like to use this little snippet of code to cause my batch files to prompt for elevation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592